# Twist of Elliptic curve $E_D: Dy^2=x^3+ax+b$ is not isomorphic to $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$.

Let $E/K: y^2=x^3+ax+b$ be an elliptic curve.

Let $E_D: Dy^2=x^3+ax+b$ is called a quadratic twist of $E/K$ by a square free integer $D$.

This curve is isomorphic over $K(\sqrt{D})$ because there is an isomorphism $E(K(\sqrt{D})\cong E_D(K(\sqrt{D}))$ given by $(x,y)\to (x,y/\sqrt{D})$.

My question is, are $E$ and $E_D$ **not isomorphic** over $K$?
How can I prove that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably want to say $D$ is a square-free integer.

Comment: This is explained in detail in Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" Chapter X. Generally, $E$ and $E_D$ are not isomorphic over $K$.

Comment: @K02 I understand. $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ and $y^2=x^3+ADx+BD^2$ has the same j-invariant, but $B/A$ and $DB/A$ is not equivalent modulo $(K^{\times})^2$.

Comment: @K02 user297024's comment is deleted. What happende between you and user297024 ?

Comment: @K02  Why you deleted the comment ? This is my question. This kind of conversation can be rude for me.

Comment: @K02 can you please pin point the reference?

Comment: The reference is X.2 Theorem 2.2, and additionally Example 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

In general they are not isomorphic. Here is an argument I think should work.

Suppose there were an isomorphism $\phi:E\to E_D$ defined over $K$. Now take your isomorphism over $K(\sqrt{D})$ and compose to get an automorphism $E\to E$ defined over $K(\sqrt{D})$. By general theory, you can pick $E$ such that its only automorphisms are the identity and the inverse homomorphism $[-1]$ (say by making sure the $j$-invariant is not equal to $0$ or $1728$ and using Theorem III.10.1 of Silverman’s AEC). Then by precomposing the isomorphism $E\to E_D$ by $[-1]$ if you have to, you know that $E\to E_D$ is an isomorphism over $K$ which is the identity. This is impossible unless $D$ were $1$.

Comment: Same argument more abstractly, the set of isomorphisms between two objects in a category is bijective with the set of automorphisms of one of them. Since (ignoring special $j$-invariants) $E_{K(\sqrt{D})}$ has two automorphisms, it can't have three different isomorphisms to its twist.